# pfSense: Possible to traffic capture the actual WAN port?

Tags: pfsense, pppoe, packet-capture

The pfSense router seems to have having problems connecting to the internet. My modem, and my ISP, confirm that i have sync, but at the same time pfSense sometimes just will not connect (using **PPPoE**).

i want to try to debug the problem, by watching the **PPPoE** connection trying to get built-up, which typically is of the form:

### 1. PADI

pfSense broadcasts a PPPoE Active Discovery Initiation (PADI) packet out to my ISP:

```
DESTINATION_ADDR: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff     ;broadcast mac address
SOURCE_ADDR:      00:01:02:3d:71:85     ;pfSense WAN adapter mac address
ETHER_TYPE:       8863                  ;PPPoE Discovery stage
PAYLOAD:          11090000
                  1                     ;Version always 0x1
                   1                    ;Type always 0x1
                    09                  ;Code: 0x09 = PADI
                      0000              ;Session ID: 0x0000
```

### 2. PADO

The ISP then responds with a PPPoE Active Discovery Offer (PADO) packet:

```
DESTINATION_ADDR: 00:01:02:3d:71:85     ;pfSense WAN adapter mac address
SOURCE_ADDR:      00:90:1a:a0:a1:f4     ;ISP's PPPoE server mac address
ETHER_TYPE:       8863                  ;PPPoE Discovery stage
PAYLOAD:          11070000
                  1                     ;Version always 0x1
                   1                    ;Type always 0x1
                    07                  ;Code: 0x07 = PADO
                      0000              ;Session ID: 0x0000
```

### 3. PADR

pfSense then requests to start a PPPoE session with the guy who responded to its broadcast by sending a PPPoE Active Discovery Request (PADR) packet to them:

```
DESTINATION_ADDR: 00:90:1a:a0:a1:f4   ;ISP's PPPoE server mac address
SOURCE_ADDR:      00:01:02:3d:71:85   ;pfSense WAN adapter mac address
ETHER_TYPE:       8863                ;PPPoE Discovery stage
PAYLOAD:          11190000
                  1                   ;Version always 0x1
                   1                  ;Type always 0x1
                    19                ;Code: 0x19 = PADR
                      0000            ;Session ID: 0x0000
```

### 4. PADS

My ISP then responds with a session ID in a The PPPoE Active Discovery Session-confirmation (PADS) packet:

```
DESTINATION_ADDR: 00:01:02:3d:71:85   ;pfSense WAN adapter mac address
SOURCE_ADDR:      00:90:1a:a0:a1:f4   ;ISP's PPPoE server mac address
ETHER_TYPE:       8863                ;PPPoE Discovery stage
PAYLOAD:          11651234
                  1                   ;Version always 0x1
                   1                  ;Type always 0x1
                    65                ;Code: 0x65 = PADS
                      1234            ;Session ID: 0x1234
```

...and on it goes.

i want to monitor the **PPPoE** session creation. i want to see *if/when* pfSense is broadcasting a `PADI` initiation packet. i want to see **if** my ISP **isn't** responding with a `PADO`. i want to capture the packets on the **WAN** interface.

Those of you who are sharp will realize the problem. i want to capture packets on the **actual** WAN interface of the computer, not the PPPoE "WAN" interface, which is not up yet. It's not up yet because the PPPoE connection isn't up yet.

i want to capture packets on the wire, not packets going out the PPPoE virtual connection.

Is it possible to capture packets on the WAN port, with PPPoE as the method for connecting to the internet, with pfSense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to do it via SSH and not the GUI Diagnostics>Packet capture screen though, as it'll capture on the ng0 PPPoE interface. Just tcpdump as normal on the actual Ethernet interface being used for the PPPoE connection. Send it to file and pull it across to a machine with Wireshark for easier analysis. Something like:

tcpdump -i em0 -s 0 -w /tmp/pppoe.pcap

to grab everything on em0 to the file /tmp/pppoe.pcap

Answer (score 3):

To expand upon Chris's answer, the actual command i used was:

```
>tcpdump -i xl0 -e 'not (pppoes and ip)'
```

Where

```
-i [interface]
```

specifies my WAN interface, which for me is `xl0`

```
-e
```

include the source and destination MAC addresses, so i can see who is sending what packets to who

```
'not (pppoes and ip)'
```

is an **expression** that says i want to *exclude* **ip** packets inside 
of a `PPPoE S`ession packet.

**Note:** tcpdump has options to monitor just the PPPoE "discovery" packets (PADI, PADO, PADR, PADS):

```
>tcpdump -i xl0 -e pppoed
```

This would show *just* the PPPoE discovery packets. i preferred the other syntax, because once the PPPoE session is established, i then get to see login/password authentication with my ISP, as well as IP/DNS/route/MTU information.

---

This led me to discover that pfSense is sending a **PPPoE Active Discovery Terminate** (PADT) packet out of the blue. That is why my link is going down - pfSense is hanging up randomly.

The PADT tag indicates the end of the session, and nobody is allowed to send anymore packets on that session. From [RFC2516 - A Method for Transmitting PPP Over Ethernet (PPPoE)](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2516.html):

> 5.5 The PPPoE Active Discovery Terminate (PADT) packet
>
> This packet may be sent anytime
>   after a session is established to
>   indicate that a PPPoE session has been
>   terminated.  It may be sent by
>   either the Host or the Access
>   Concentrator.  The DESTINATION_ADDR
>   field is a unicast Ethernet address,
>   the CODE field is set to 0xa7    and
>   the SESSION_ID MUST be set to indicate
>   which session is to be    terminated. 
>   No TAGs are required.
>
> When a PADT is received, no further
>   PPP traffic is allowed to be sent
>   using that session.  Even normal PPP
>   termination packets MUST NOT be
>   sent after sending or receiving a
>   PADT.  A PPP peer SHOULD use the
>   PPP protocol itself to bring down a
>   PPPoE session, but the PADT MAY    be
>   used when PPP can not be used.

My next question will, of course, be

> Why is pfSense hanging up randomly?

---

The answer is that an ATM switch inside Bell Canada's concentrator is faulty. The card would randomly reset, losing any memory of my PPPoE session.

Meanwhile, my router doesn't know its PPPoE session is no longer valid, and continues to try to communicate over that same **SessionID**. The concentrator, not recognizing that session, ignores any packets coming from me.

pfSense, after sensing 10 seconds of no traffic, begins sending **LCP Echo-Requests**, at 10s intervals, to the remote network. After 40 seconds of not getting any responses, pfSense brings down the PPPoE session and starts a new one:

```
PADI
```

The concentrator, seeing a broadcast requesting to start a session, responds; and shortly thereafter the new PPPoE session is established.

**Current (*faulty*) ATM switch MAC:**

`00:90:1a:a0:a1:f4` *[Unisphere Solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unisphere_Networks) (was: redstone communications)*

**New ATM switch MAC:**

*to be installed 8/6/2010*